# Why do people often say Linux is an Operating System?

Tags: linux, kernel, system

I'm sort of new to this scene, and I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around something...
I often see many people referring to Linux as an operating system. I am fairly sure it is a kernel (commonly paired with GNU to form the GNU/Linux operating system, then finally made into a distribution?).

I used to just disregard it thinking they made a mistake, but I'm even seeing the Systems Engineer at NetScape refer to Linux as an operating system.
Looking for guidance, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not programming related.

Comment: Apparently you're not the only one...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy

Comment: "Why do people often say Linux is an Operating System?" - for the same reason they say that C is a subset of C++...

Comment: In his original annoucement, Linus himself announced Linux as a (free) operating system (*"just a hobby, won't be big and professional like gnu"*). I tend to think appeal to authority can be used here and Linus knew what he meant when he annouced for the first time that he had created a (free) operating system. Long story short: it's both a kernel and an OS.

Comment: Read also the wikipages about [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29), [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [Linux distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)

Answer (score 3):

There's a kernel and an operating system. See for more details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel